# Perl kill process with timeout ignored

Tags: perl, process

I was testing my source code, in which the child process calls several other programs (some of which are C++).

```
#Other variables and functions

my $MAX_TIME = 10;#testing 10 minutes
my $timeRemaining = $MAX_TIME * 60;
my $pid = fork();
if ( $pid == 0 ) {
  #child process
  my $nowTime = localtime;
  print "Run started at $nowTime\n";

  #This run() calls a for loop in perl, in each iteration there are several C++ programs
  run();

  setpgrp(0,0);
}
elsif ($pid > 0){
  my $nowTime = localtime;
  eval{
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
      kill -9, $pid;
      print "Run completed at $nowTime\nJob time out for $MAX_TIME minutes\n";
      log();
      die "TIMEOUT!\n";
    };
    alarm $timeRemaining;
    waitpid($pid, 0);
  };
  print "Run completed at $nowTime with no timeout\n";
}
```

When I checked the print out, I noticed that after 10 minutes, the "Run completed at $nowTime with no timeout\n" part gets printed out, and the child process is still executing. The `die "TIMEOUT!\n";` part in the parent process does not get executed.
Is it because of the C++ programs that the perl program calls cannot be killed once it started?

Comment: Tip: Avoid negative signal numbers. It can cause confusion. (For example, shell command `kill -9 $pid` sends the signal the the process, not the process group.) Use negative PIDs like in the shell and in the system call: `kill 9, -$pid;`, or better yet, `kill KILL => -$pid;`

Comment: Thank you. I just noticed that if I replace my actual `run()` program with some dummy code like `print current_time(),"\n"; sleep 1200; print current_time(),"\n";` the second line of `print current_time(),"\n";` will still be executed at time 1200 (20min), even though the parent process is supposed to kill the child.

Comment: Tip: `setpgrp(0,0);` can be written `setpgrp();`

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `kill` is failing because `$pid` isn't a process group.

```
run();
setpgrp(0,0);
```

should be

```
setpgrp(0,0);
run();
```

---

Secondly, the reason you see

```
Run completed at $nowTime with no timeout
```

even when there's a timeout is that you execute

```
print "Run completed at $nowTime with no timeout\n";
```

whether there's a timeout or not.

---

Thirdly, you don't disable the `alarm` when the child is reaped. Add

```
alarm(0);
```

---

Fourthly, you expect `$nowTime` to contain the current time without making it so.

---

Finally, you still need to reap your child even if you kill it. (Ok, this can be skipped if the parent exits immediately anyway.)

---

Fixed:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw( strftime );

sub current_time { strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime) }

sub run {
  print("a\n");
  system('perl', '-e', 'sleep 3;');
  print("b\n");
  system('perl', '-e', 'sleep 3;');
  print("c\n");
}

my $MAX_TIME = 5;
my $pid = fork();
die($!) if !defined($pid);
if ($pid) {
  if (eval{
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
      kill KILL => -$pid;
      die "TIMEOUT!\n";
    };
    alarm($MAX_TIME);
    waitpid($pid, 0);
    alarm(0);
    return 1;
  }) {
    print "[".current_time()."] Run completed.\n";
  } else {
    die($@) if $@ ne "TIMEOUT!\n";
    print "[".current_time()."] Run timed out.\n";
    waitpid($pid, 0);
    print "[".current_time()."] Child reaped.\n";
  }
} else {
  print "[".current_time()."] Run started.\n";
  setpgrp(0,0);
  run();
}
```

Output:

```
[2017-05-11 14:58:06] Run started.
a
b
[2017-05-11 14:58:11] Run timed out.
[2017-05-11 14:58:11] Child reaped.
```

Comment: Thanks. I found changing the order of `run();` and `setpgrp(0,0);` definitely helped in fixing it. Can I know in more details why we should do `setpgrp(0,0)` first?

Comment: Because you'll never get to it otherwise